# filter sql query for last 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to filter some results for the last 24 hours only. I have timestamps in the time column and came up with this but it doesn't filter for last 24 hours it shows everything.

```
$last_day = "SELECT site_id, time, COUNT(*) AS site_num FROM url_visits WHERE time < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) GROUP BY site_id ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC";
```

Does anyone know how I can make this query work for the last 24 hours? It works correctly for the grouping etc just not the last 24 hours. Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is what ended up working and the only solution I found to work in case anyone ever comes across this and are looking to do the same thing.

```
SELECT site_id, time, COUNT(*) AS site_num FROM url_visits WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY site_id ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: change `<` to `>`, you select all where the time is older than 24 hours.

Comment: I think `time` must be bigger than `DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)`

Comment: i tried > but then everything goes blank and nothing shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using and the only thing that worked. Hoped this helps someone else.

```
SELECT site_id, time, COUNT(*) AS site_num FROM url_visits WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY site_id ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
time > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

rather than

```
time < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Comment: thats what i have been trying but it just seems to show nothing. i think its my code then.

Comment: Test the query directly to see if there's data matching the query

Answer (score 0):

```
$last_day = "SELECT site_id, time, COUNT(*) AS site_num FROM url_visits WHERE time > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) GROUP BY site_id ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC";
```

Changed the comparison

Comment: I tried that and nothing shows it goes blank, maybe its my code then.

Comment: What is the data type of 'time'?